# React router v4 Route doesn't display the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Reading over stack overflow and the internet i can't find a solution for a problem that seems simple to solve, but... i can't get it.

The problem is pretty simple, `<Route path={`${match.path}/notas`} component={Dashboard} />` doesnt' render the `Dashboard` component... why? No idea.

Here is the general code:

The index, where the routes begin:

```
const rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootNode
)
```

The App component, main layout:

```
class App extends Component {
  
  componentWillMount() {
    const data = { loggedIn: false }
    sessionStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Helmet>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <title>{APP_TITLE}</title>
        </Helmet>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

And the Home component:

```
const Home = ({match}) => {
  return <section className="home--grid">
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="home--grid">
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}`} exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/videos`} component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/notas`} component={Dashboard} />
        <Redirect to={`${match.url}`} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </section>
}
```

Is that simple, nothing special... the idea is `Dashboard` will display some json content based on the `match.path`, but when i navigate to the established path, the app doesn't display anything, just a void `<section>`, no idea why...

A fast note: the first render of `Home` renders perfectly the Sidebar and the `Dashboard` related to the first route.

Here is the navigation to get to the component:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return <nav className="home--sidenav">
    <ul className="sidenav--items">
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/home">Total</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/home/videos">Videos</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/home/notas">Notas</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
}
```

**Edit**
By petiton, the Dashboard component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.match.path}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ dashboard: state.dashboard })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
```

yep, is that simple for now...

### Update

I've been experimenting around, my first thought was "update blocker" but any of the posible fixes in the documentation didn't work, wrapping the `Dashboard` component into a `withRouter` function like:

`const WrappedDash = withRouter(Dashboard)`

and passing it into a route, trying to render the child component with

`render={() => <Dashboard />}`

nor passing explicitly the `location` object to Dashboard in the render method.

Every case is the same, NavLink take me to the dictated route, and it renders nothing (a void section element).

The weird case is, even if I make a plain route like `/videos` instead `${match}/videos`, the router keep rendering nothing. I thought that can be a problem with authenticated routes but it doesnt't make any sense for me.

Comment: can you show your Dashboard component, so we can see all the component that participate in the flow

Comment: It sounds to me like update blocking, although your sample didn't include any redux/shouldComponentUpdate code.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking

Comment: Sure, i will update the code, wait a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed the problem, it was in the `exact` declaration of the Home route, I was expecting exactly the home route to render the content.

Yes, is a very stupid detail but it matters a lot:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
```

The above code will not render anything else that the component of `/home`, and the code below (the inclusive route), will render everything:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
```

It was that simple, I'm sorry for the question but little details like this are difficult to see if it is your first time with new tools.

Answer (score 1):

In app

```
 <Switch>
    <ProtectedRoute path="/home" exact render={ () => <Home/>} />
    <Route path="/" exact render={ () => <Login/>} />
  </Switch>
```

In home

```
<Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}`} exact render={ () => <Dashboard/>} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/videos`} render={ () => <Dashboard/>} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/notas`} render={() => <Dashboard/>} />
        <Redirect to={`${match.url}`} />
 </Switch>
```

Need to use the render prop.

Comment: But why? I didn't test this yet, but i have the theorical question.